# How to insert downloaded images name into database, i dont want to insert by uploading image

Tags: php, database, image, download, insert

I am able to read the images name which is already present/downloaded in  folder, but need to insert in database, how can this be done
and i dont want to insert it to database by uploading the image

```
<?php
// to fetch images name from directory in array format
$directory = glob('C:/xampp/htdocs/mail'); // your directory

foreach (glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename)
{
    echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to *insert into database*, what research have you done, SO is not a coding service, you can find plenty of tutorials and manuals on inserting into a databases.

Comment: i am able to download all attachments and images from email, and now i need to insert those attachments into the database, am only able to find solutions regarding uploading the image and then the image name is stored in the database, but how vl i insert the downloaded images.

Answer (score 1):

- Store all the file names in an array
- Make connection with database. For example:

`$conn = mysqli_connect( $hostname, $user, $pass, $dbname );`

- Use a foreach loop.

For example:

```
foreach (glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO demo (fileName) VALUES ('$filename')";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($res){
        echo "$filename was inserted";
    }
    else{
        echo "$filename was not inserted";
    }
}
```

Where, demo = name of your table and fileName is the column in which you want to store the name of your files.

> **NOTE:** I've used MySQLi Procedural. You can use MySQLi Object-oriented or PDO also.

**External References:**

[MySQLi Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)

[PDO Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)

[Connecting to DB](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

[Inserting data in DB](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help and suggestions... 
I got the required output

```
$servername="Localhost";
$dbname = "email_tab";
$username="root";
$pwd="root";

// To check the established connection
$conn = new mysqli( $servername,$username,$pwd,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//fetch images in the folder
$dir = glob('C:/xampp/htdocs/mail'); 
$images = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
$filename=array();  // to assign images to array

foreach($images as $image)
{
   $filename[]=$image;
}
```

// incrementing using $cnt to fetch all 
    images

```
for($cnt=0;$cnt<=3;$cnt++)  
{

$emailimage=$filename[$cnt]; // passing $cnt as to fetch all images
// insert to the database
echo $sql= "INSERT INTO email_attachment ( `ino`, `is_deleted`, `status`, `email_master_sno`, `attachment_path`, `filename`) VALUES ('1', '0', '1', '1', 'NULL', '".$emailimage."')";
$conn->query($sql);

}

echo $emailimage;
```